# Convert specific static pages to Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have 30-40 static HTML pages which are linked together. There are 2 pages which need API integration. Is there a way to achieve this in Angular without having to convert the entire bunch of HTML's to Angular? The API's to be integrated are basic GET API's. I would want to read parameters from the url in between the two pages which require API integration.

Apologies if the question is lame.

Comment: You can simply make each page (as needed) be it's own Angular app. This is what the Angular team intends you to do when you want to slowly migrate your app to Angular. Follow any Angular tutorial, just skip over anything related to `ngRoute` or `ui-router`.

Comment: I had thought of the same solution. Is creating multiple apps a good practice? Do you have any documentation which speaks about this?

Comment: If you were starting from scratch, no that would not be a good practice. But for migrating an existing app to Angular, it's what the Angular team recommends. They used to talk about this specific scenario on the Angular web site, but I checked it before I commented and couldn't find any references to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early days, the Angular web site discussed migrating an existing app to Angular. They showed how you could run a little Angular app within an existing application. I can't seem to find these references anymore.

This is done by using the `ng-app` directive on a given HTML element within your page. It can be any element within the DOM hierarchy, for example: a nested `<div ng-app="myApp">` somewhere on your page. All the child elements under this div will be part of the Angular app.

Since you have multiple static pages where you wish to run Angular, you can start off by adding isolated apps to each static page as needed. Use the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service to read params from the query string to initialize each app.